# How air suspension lockout works

Tags: suspension, lock

Can anyone please explain how air suspension lockout works? I mean physically what happens inside the shock?
 There are also multiple setting in lockout, how are they implemted?

Comment: @DWGKNZ not sure if it. So do you mean that any air fork still has oil damper?

Comment: Duplicate of the above question which has a good answer. This question asks specifically about "air suspension" which refers to an air spring rather than a coil spring. However lock-out works on the damping circuit rather than the spring so the above answer stands.

Comment: yep was just explaining that. Air sprung forks use an air spring and oil damper. The spring provides resistance and the damper prevents oscillation. So essentially the spring absorbs the bump and the damper slows the springs return.

Comment: But once you lock your fork, what changes? In those topic it's said that oil valve is closed. So oil flows even when forks suspends, but with different from damping valve?

Comment: Not sure what your asking on your last question. When a fork is not locked out the valve controls the speed at which oil flows, this stops the fork from snapping back by slowing down the oil movement. The lock out shuts the valve so the oil can't go anywhere so the fork becomes rigid. The spring is unable to be engaged.